# how to use drag & drop on the Table Component antd

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Recently i get project from other team and my client want to change some part from admin page.i want to ask how to set spesific order for data from database.for example in this case my client want to set the jabatan in spesific order like example they want to put executive director on number one and so on.i hear we can use the drag & drop on the Table Component so i want to ask how to change the code so i can use drag and drop Table Component Sorry for the bad english

[image: here the table]

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { Space, Card, Table, Button, Typography, message } from 'antd';

import { EDIT_MANAJEMEN } from '@constants/urls';

import type { ManagementProps } from '@customTypes/aboutUs';

import fetchRequest from '@utils/fetcher';
import PreviewImage from '@components/PreviewImage';

const { Title } = Typography;

const Management = () => {
  const [managementData, setManagementData] = useState<ManagementProps[]>([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const managementColumns = [
    {
      title: 'No',
      dataIndex: 'key',
      key: 'key'
    },
    {
      title: 'Jabatan',
      dataIndex: 'otherData',
      render: (_: string, record: any) => <>{record.otherData.position}</>,
    },
    {
      title: 'Foto',
      dataIndex: 'url',
      render: (_: string, record: any) => (
        <PreviewImage
          key="key"
          buttonName="Lihat Foto"
          mediaUrl={record.url}
        ></PreviewImage>
      ),
    },
    {
      title: 'Nama',
      dataIndex: 'title',
    },
    {
      title: 'Narasi',
      dataIndex: 'content',
      render: (_: string, record: any) => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: record.content}}></div>,
    },
    {
      title: 'Aksi',
      key: 'action',
      render: (_: string, record: any) => (
        <Button
          type="link"
          className="button-link-grey"
          onClick={() => navigate(EDIT_MANAJEMEN + '/' + record.id)}
        >
          Ubah
        </Button>
      ),
      width: 150,
    },
  ];

  const getManagementData = async () => {
    try {
      await fetchRequest({
        method: 'GET',
        path: 'resource/about-us/management',
      }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.error) {
          setManagementData(response.management || {});
        } else {
          message.error(response.error.message);
        }
      });
    } catch (error: any) {
      message.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getManagementData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Space direction="vertical" size="middle" style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
      <Card title={<Title level={4}>Manajemen</Title>}>
        <Table
          columns={managementColumns}
          dataSource={managementData}
          pagination={false}
        />
      </Card>
    </Space>
  );
};

export default Management;
```

please tell me how so i can use drag and drop Table Component because i cant make it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you have to add the library dnd-kit yo your project.

[dnd-kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dnd-kit/core)

Then, you have to follow the example provided by antd in the documentation
[Documentation](https://ant.design/components/table#components-table-demo-drag-sorting)

```
import type { DragEndEvent } from '@dnd-kit/core';
import { DndContext, PointerSensor, useSensor, useSensors } from '@dnd-kit/core';
import { restrictToVerticalAxis } from '@dnd-kit/modifiers';
import {
  SortableContext,
  arrayMove,
  useSortable,
  verticalListSortingStrategy,
} from '@dnd-kit/sortable';
import { CSS } from '@dnd-kit/utilities';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'antd';
import type { ColumnsType } from 'antd/es/table';

interface DataType {
  key: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string;
}

const columns: ColumnsType<DataType> = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
  },
];

interface RowProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableRowElement> {
  'data-row-key': string;
}

const Row = (props: RowProps) => {
  const { attributes, listeners, setNodeRef, transform, transition, isDragging } = useSortable({
    id: props['data-row-key'],
  });

  const style: React.CSSProperties = {
    ...props.style,
    transform: CSS.Transform.toString(transform && { ...transform, scaleY: 1 }),
    transition,
    cursor: 'move',
    ...(isDragging ? { position: 'relative', zIndex: 9999 } : {}),
  };

  return <tr {...props} ref={setNodeRef} style={style} {...attributes} {...listeners} />;
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([
    {
      key: '1',
      name: 'John Brown',
      age: 32,
      address:
        'Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text',
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      name: 'Jim Green',
      age: 42,
      address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
    {
      key: '3',
      name: 'Joe Black',
      age: 32,
      address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
    },
  ]);

  const sensors = useSensors(
    useSensor(PointerSensor, {
      activationConstraint: {
        // https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/sensors/pointer#activation-constraints
        distance: 1,
      },
    }),
  );

  const onDragEnd = ({ active, over }: DragEndEvent) => {
    if (active.id !== over?.id) {
      setDataSource((prev) => {
        const activeIndex = prev.findIndex((i) => i.key === active.id);
        const overIndex = prev.findIndex((i) => i.key === over?.id);
        return arrayMove(prev, activeIndex, overIndex);
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <DndContext sensors={sensors} modifiers={[restrictToVerticalAxis]} onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <SortableContext
        // rowKey array
        items={dataSource.map((i) => i.key)}
        strategy={verticalListSortingStrategy}
      >
        <Table
          components={{
            body: {
              row: Row,
            },
          }}
          rowKey="key"
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={dataSource}
        />
      </SortableContext>
    </DndContext>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In your case, you have to add the function onDragAdd() , create the object const sensors and add the component name Row for make draggable lines.

Finally, you have to wrap your Table component with the SortableContext.

Comment: how to add key for this  setDataSource((prev) => {
        const activeIndex = prev.findIndex((i) => i.key === active.id);
        const overIndex = prev.findIndex((i) => i.key === over?.id);
        return arrayMove(prev, activeIndex, overIndex);

Comment: A "ugly" solution is, in the getManagementData() , iterate in the array you get to put a property key to each element.


if (!response.error) {
  for (let i = 0 ; i < response.management?.length ; i++) {
    response.management[i].key = i ;
  }
  setManagementData(response.management || {});
}

Comment: What is the structure of your response.management ?